# Remove certain instances of item in a list?

Tags: python, list, object, reduce, instances

I'm working on a code to count the amount of lego pieces needed to create other pieces (ex. 2x2 =2 1x1) that are within a list and I have this portion working. However, I also want to return a new list after this 'combining' process that removes lego pieces that were either used or combined (and as such, are no longer available). The code I have now strips ALL instances of the lego, rather than just the ones which are 'used'. I am wondering if there is a way to remove a certain item from a list times a number. Thanks in advance.

```
import hw4_util
legos = hw4_util.read_legos()

print 'Current legos',legos

def lego_work(lego,q,leglist): 
        count=0
        num1x1= leglist.count('1x1')
        num2x1= leglist.count('2x1')
        num2x2= leglist.count('2x2')
        num4x2= leglist.count('4x2')
        if lego =='1x1':
                count = num1x1
        elif lego == '2x1':
                if num2x1 == 0:
                        count = (num1x1/2)
                        leglist2= filter(lambda a: a != '1x1', leglist)
                else:
                        count= num2x1
                        leglist2=filter(lambda a: a != '2x1', leglist)
        elif lego =='2x2':
                if num2x2==0 and (num2x1/2) ==0:
                        count = (num1x1/4)
                        leglist2=  filter(lambda a: a != '1x1', leglist)
                elif num2x2==0 and num2x1>0:
                        count= num2x1
                        leglist2= filter(lambda a: a != '2x1', leglist)
                else:
                        count=num2x2
                        leglist2= filter(lambda a: a != '2x2', leglist)
        elif lego== '4x2':
                if num4x2==0 and (num2x2/2) and (num2x1/4)==0:
                        count = (num1x1/8)
                        leglist2= filter(lambda a: a != '1x1', leglist)
                elif num4x2==0 and num2x2==0 and num2x1>0:
                        count= num2x1
                        leglist2= filter(lambda a: a != '2x1', leglist)
                elif num4x2==0 and num2x2>0:
                        count=num2x2  
                        leglist2= filter(lambda a: a != '2x2', leglist)
                else:
                        count=num4x2
                        leglist2= filter(lambda a: a != '4x2', leglist)
        if count>=q:
                print 'You can use',q,lego,'legos for this.'
        elif count<q:
                print  " I don't have",q,lego,'legos.' 
        print 
        print 'Current legos:',leglist2
legotype= raw_input('Type of lego wanted =>')
print legotype
quantity= input('Quantity wanted =>')
print quantity

print lego_work(legotype,quantity,legos)
```

Comment: If you have the index of the element in the list, use `somelist.pop(index)`. If you don't have the indices, *and* you don't care about identical pieces, you can use `index = somelist.find(piece); somelist.pop(index)`.

Comment: That seems like it would still remove all instances of the lego in the list, rather than just some.

Comment: How would that remove all instances? `index` is only one value, thus removes only one. Have you tried?

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: This can be much simpler. Create a loop to run `q` times, and process one block each time. That way, if you run out of blocks part-way through, you'll use the big ones as much as possible before switching to smaller ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `leglist.remove('2x1')` to remove one of the parts from the list.